# Where to put helper-scripts with GNU autoconf/automake?

Tags: autoconf, automake

I'm working on a project that will be distributed with GNU autoconf/automake, and I have a set of bash scripts which call awk scripts.  I would like the bash scripts to end up in the $PATH, but not the awk scripts.  How should I insert these into the project?  Should they be put in with other binaries?

Also, is there a way to determine the final location of the file after installation?  I presume that /usr/local/bin isn't *always* where the executables end up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like this to Makefile.am

```
scriptsdir = $(prefix)/bin
scripts_DATA = awkscript1 awkscript2
```

In this case it will install awkscript in $(prefix)/bin (you can also use $(bindir)).

Note: Dont forget that the first should be named name + dir (scripts -> scriptsdir) and the second should be name + _DATA (scripts -> scripts_DATA).

Comment: Augh no. Use `pkglibexec_DATA` or `pkglibexec_SCRIPTS`, which will install (by default) to `$prefix/libexec/$package`. That's what libexecdir is for: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html "The libexec/ directory contains small helper programs called by other programs". It also means if you're on a distro that doesn't like libexec, the packager can change where these scripts go by passing `--libexecdir=/usr/lib` to configure. See also http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Uniform

Comment: What's the difference between `libexec_SCRIPTS` or `libexec_PROGRAMS` and `pkglibexec_SCRIPTS` or `pkglibexec_PROGRAMS`?

Comment: Is there some sort of global libexec and package specific libexec? Does that global libexec is intended for execution by other programs but not by users, while package specific libexec is only meant to be used by programs in your package?

Answer (score 7):

You can just list the scripts that you want to be installed in Makefile.am:

```
bin_SCRIPTS = foo bar
```

This will cause foo and bar to be installed during make install.  To get the path to their final location, you can use @bindir@ in foo.in and let configure build foo for you.  For example, in configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo bar])
```

and then in foo.in:

```
#!/bin/sh

prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
bindir=@bindir@
echo bindir = $bindir
```

Keep in mind that the person running configure may specify any of --prefix, --exec_prefix, or
--bindir, and the installation may be redirected with a DESTDIR.  Using the technique described here, DESTDIR will not be taken into account and the script will be installed in a location other than the path that it will echo.  This is by design, and is the correct behavior, as usually a DESTDIR installation is used to create a tarball that will eventually be unpacked into the filesystem in such a way that the bindir in the script becomes valid.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should have gotten the checkmark. +1

Comment: @Andras budinszky suggests using `dist_bin_SCRIPTS`, but that is incorrect in this case.  The file `foo` should not be in the distribution tarball, because it will be generated from `foo.in` which will be in the tarball due to its appearance in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan, in response to your additional question: if you want to replace the value of prefix at the time of build, you will need to:

1. rename your script 'myscript' to 'myscript.in'
2. add a rule to configure.ac to generate it at the bottom
3. use a macro I made called [AS_AC_EXPAND](http://autostars.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/autostars/autostars/ac-expand/as-ac-expand.m4)
4. use it like this:

   AS_AC_EXPAND(BINDIR, $bindir)
5. in your 'myscript.in', you can now use @BINDIR@ and it will get expanded to the full path where the script will end up being installed.

Note that you shouldn't use PREFIX directly, any of the installation directories can potentially be changed so you really want to use the value passed to configure for bindir and expand that.

Comment: m4sh reserves for itself those names that begin "AS_".  By naming a macro "AS_", you stomp on m4sh's namespace.  Please read section 10.2 of the autoconf documentation.

Comment: Where is your `AS_AC_EXPAND` macro!?

Answer (score 0):

If the awk scripts won't go into the main bin directory (prefix/bin), then you need to place them in an appropriate sub-directory - probably of lib but possibly libexec or share (since the awk scripts are probably platform neutral).

Correct: software won't necessarily end up in /usr/local/bin; on my machine, /usr/local/bin is managed by MIS and all the software I install therefore goes under /usr/gnu/.  I use: ./configure --prefix=/usr/gnu to get the software installed where I want it.

You can embed the value of PREFIX in the bash scripts -- effectively, you will 'compile' the scripts to include the install location.  Be aware of problems during the build testing - you may need to locate the scripts relative to the current directory first and relative to PREFIX later.

Comment: How would I cause automake to replace ${prefix} in the bash scripts? should I make them some sort of \_BIN item, as opposed to \_DATA item?