# Where to put pre-built binaries with automake?

Tags: c++, packaging, autotools, automake, ampl

I am writing this question in part based on a [related question on helper-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94161/where-to-put-helper-scripts-with-gnu-autoconf-automake).

I have a C++ software system built with autotools. For a small part of its functionality, my system uses a closed-source pre-built binary: [AMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL). I'm a freely-available student version of their software. Suppose the name of the AMPL binary file I call from within my C++ code is `ampl-student`. I run it from within my code using a `system(...)` call.

I would like `ampl-student` to be moved to `/usr/bin` along with the binary of my compiled C++ code when "make install" is run. Where in the **Makefile.am** should I add `ampl-student`. Should I just add it to the `bin_PROGRAMS` variable?

A related question is should I even put `ampl-student` in `/usr/bin`. Is there a more appropriate place for a "helper binary"?

I think this is, in general, a bad idea since distributing a pre-built binary along with the code doesn't guarantee that the binary will run on the end user's computer. But in this case, the user base is very small, and I happen to know that they are all using the same system configurations. So we are in fact using the deb package as a way to keep everyone updated of new releases of the software system.

*Edit 1:* I should emphasize that the question is first and foremost asking for where to specify `ampl-student` in the **Makefile.am** file used by autotools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd install it in `$(pkglibexecdir)`:

```
pkglibexec_PROGRAMS = ampl-student

# If you need to know the path in your code
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DPKGLIBEXECDIR=\"$(pkglibexecdir)\"
```

It's not really a user program, so this installs it somewhere out of the way. By default, this is going to be `$(prefix)/libexec/$(package)`.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you want to ship the software or it is going to be locally installed in the /usr/bin and all the users are going to access the software from there.

1. If you are going to install it in /usr/bin and you want to put AMPL there too, define a symbolic constant to the path and use it. 

   #define AMPL /usr/bin/ampl-student
   whichever source file you want to use it you can add,
   system(AMPL);
2. If you want to ship the binary of your code, then you should put ampl-bin in the bin directory of your software or create a dir. structure as:

< your tool >/src
< your tool >/bin - you can put ampl-student also here
< your tool >/third-party/< tool1 > ....< tooln >/bin/ you can put ampl-student here

As you have rightly mentioned before distributing ampl-student make sure, it works in all platforms where the tool is supposed to run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I was more asking about what to add to Makefile.am to specify a good place for these pre-built binaries, so that when `make install` is run or the deb package is installed in Ubuntu, the `ampl-student` file ends up somewhere that makes sense (/usr/bin being what I believe makes sense, but I wasn't sure).