# automake correctly setting +x bit on dist_bin_SCRIPTS except when installed from a brew formula

Tags: homebrew, file-permissions, automake

I have a few scripts to setup my tmux development environment and I'm trying to packaging them up into a brew formula but I've hit a snag.

Locally running:

```
% ./configure
% make install
```

produces two scripts from *.in and runs `chmod +x` on each one successfully. The files it generates are both executable (0755).

The output of `ls` in the project folder after manually running `./configure && make` is:

```
~/repositories/tmuxide/scripts on :master? (2895bf9) tracking origin/master
****@****(ttys002)[1062] % ls
total 104
drwxr-xr-x   9 frankjmattia  staff   306B Jun 16 22:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 frankjmattia  staff   816B Jun 16 22:10 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 frankjmattia  staff    14K Jun 16 22:09 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 frankjmattia  staff   405B Jun 16 22:08 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r--   1 frankjmattia  staff    14K Jun 16 22:09 Makefile.in
-rwxr-xr-x   1 frankjmattia  staff   1.7K Jun 16 22:10 log-pane
-rw-r--r--   1 frankjmattia  staff   1.7K Jun 12 20:35 log-pane.in
-rwxr-xr-x   1 frankjmattia  staff   2.1K Jun 16 22:10 tmuxide
-rw-r--r--   1 frankjmattia  staff   2.1K Jun 16 22:04 tmuxide.in
```

And the output of `ls` in the folder where homebrew installs it is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tmuxide/0.0.3.j/bin on :master (3fec4c9)
*****@****(ttys002)[1056] % ls
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 frankjmattia  admin   136B Jun 16 22:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 frankjmattia  admin   204B Jun 16 22:11 ..
-r--r--r--  1 frankjmattia  admin   1.7K Jun 16 22:11 log-pane
-r--r--r--  1 frankjmattia  admin   2.1K Jun 16 22:11 tmuxide
```

Here are the important parts of the files at play:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([tmuxide], [0.0.3.j], [frankjmattia+tmuxide@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile man/Makefile scripts/Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

**scripts/Makefile.am**

```
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = tmuxide log-pane
CLEANFILES = $(dist_bin_SCRIPTS)

EXTRA_DIST = tmuxide.in log-pane.in

do_subst = sed \
    -e 's,[@]PACKAGE[@],$(PACKAGE),g' \
    -e 's,[@]PACKAGE_VERSION[@],$(PACKAGE_VERSION),g'

tmuxide: tmuxide.in Makefile
    $(do_subst) < $(srcdir)/tmuxide.in > tmuxide
    chmod +x tmuxide

log-pane: log-pane.in Makefile
    $(do_subst) < $(srcdir)/log-pane.in > log-pane
    chmod +x log-pane
```

However, when I wrap this in a brew formula, the generated files are only readable (0444).

**homebrew/tmuxide.rb**

```
require "formula"

class Tmuxide < Formula
  homepage 'https://github.com/frankjmattia/tmuxide'
  url 'https://frankjmattia.github.io/tmuxide/tmuxide-0.0.3.j.tar.gz'
  sha1 '5e51b66013a4afd60c362ce448b7e976cf7d6d6e'

  depends_on 'gnu-getopt'

  def install
    system './configure', '--disable-silent-rules',
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"

    system 'make', 'install'
  end
end
```

I can't figure out where things are going wrong and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can find the complete source at [github.com/frankjmattia/tmuxide](https://github.com/frankjmattia/tmuxide)

Comment: BTW, configure does do substitution like you are doing in build steps in **scripts/Makefile.am** using `AC_CONFIG_FILES`. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ldav1s/2abb86695dec50c96742) that does it.

Comment: Thanks for the gist. I gave your version a shot and unfortunately the files brew installs are still only readable. Also, `make clean` doesn't get rid of the generated files now.

Comment: When I tried `make install` (without brew) the scripts were installed with the right permission, as your post describes. Therefore, somewhere along the brew path is where the problem lies.  The scripts in the gist still follow the [automake clean rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html).  They aren't made by `make`, but `configure`, so `make distclean` will clean them.

Comment: Ah good to know, `make distclean` took care of it. I like the putting-it-in-configure.ac approach better than the Makefile. But I'm still unable to figure out why `brew install` is killing it. The search continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

I ran `brew install tmuxide -vd` and at the end of the run I noticed this gem

```
==> Cleaning
Fixing /usr/local/Cellar/tmuxide/0.0.3.k/bin/log-pane permissions from 755 to 444
Fixing /usr/local/Cellar/tmuxide/0.0.3.k/bin/tmuxide permissions from 755 to 444
```

Digging into the homebrew source I found this:

```ruby
[@f.bin, @f.sbin, @f.lib].select{ |d| d.exist? }.each{ |d| clean_dir d }
```

`clean_dir` basically goes through each file and if it's a binary executable or text executable file it adjusts the execute bit accordingly. If it's not, it removes the execute bit.

Then I stumbled up this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94161/where-to-put-helper-scripts-with-gnu-autoconf-automake]) which led me to believe I should have been using `libexec` to distribute these files. the `clean_dir` method didn't change anything in libexec so my file permissions were preserved but my journey was far from over.

After getting this to work I then had to symlink these to `/usr/local/bin` because `libexec` isn't in path. So I added `bin.install_symlink "#{libexec}/tmuxide"` to the formula. That worked - but it wasn't the right solution. After putzing around I went back and looked at the clean_dir method again to see what constituted a `text_executable?` pathname.

```
def text_executable?
  %r[^#!\s*\S+] === open('r') { |f| f.read(1024) }
end
```

I went back to my script (because I knew I had a shebang in there) and realized my shebang line wasn't properly formed. I made it an ordinary comment `# /usr/bin/env zsh`. After correcting that to `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` everything proceeded as normal.

@ldav1s Thanks for the good tips on automake. Your help was appreciated.